# Как вытащить текст из одного пункта sellectfield'a?(с помощью JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть selectfield:

```
 <select class="filter">
<option value=1>Name 1</option>
<option value=2>Name 2</option>
<option value=3>Name 3</option>
</select>
```

Мне нужно при выборе пользователем  какого-то пункта из селектфилда поулчить текст этого пункта(т.е. выбрал пользователь Name 2,мне надо получить этот самый Name 2).
Я повесил следующий хендлер:

```
$(document).on('change','.filter', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).text();
});
```

Однако,проблема в том,что он берет в данном случае текст не только из option выбранного пункта, он в value запихивает вообще весь текст от всех option. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: используйте $(this).val();

Comment: $(this).val(); покажет только значение value,то есть цифру. мне нужен текст между тегами <option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить текст из select :

```
 $(this).find(":selected").text();
```

Comment: Во, блин, точно, я тут `each` всякие накатал))

Answer (score 1):

```js
var value;
var text;

$(document).on('change','.filter', function (e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  value = $(this).val();
  
  $(this).children('option').each(function () {
    if($(this).val() == value){
      text = $(this).text();
    }
  });
  
  alert(text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="filter">
  <option value=1>Name 1</option>
  <option value=2>Name 2</option>
  <option value=3>Name 3</option>
</select>
```